# Best Practices for Managing SQL Code

Tags: c#, sql, separation-of-concerns

I have a issue that keeps coming up as a developer using any .NET (C# mostly) and SQL. I personally feel it is bad practice to build SQL statements in code. There are too many case scenarios that may appear that you may not be aware of. If you ever done a SQL audit, it becomes infuriating creating unit tests for every case, and is time consuming. Especially when SQL grows. Also as you build the sql and other developers tag-on it becomes less and less efficient. Most usually start with 'WHERE 1=1' so you can just create a bunch of AND's to the build structure.

My previous thoughts were to use .sql files. Load them in and you can just create a file with a naming convention for each case you want. Simple enough to choose what you need with a switch statement and very easy to read. However the issue with this is to be sure to make it thread safe.

At some point I changed into adding them to resource files so that they couldn't /easily/ be edited. I even encrypted them eventually because the SO at one company felt they should be. At this point I keep thinking about storing sql in a database (encrypted) instead of files The only real query you'd have to make thread safe is the one that retrieves other sql statements.

My question is: What other options have people come up with? What is best practice? I did research and came up with no uniform way of storing sql statements for code.

Comment: Your issue seems to be maintenance and evolution of queries, but it is not clear to me why you believe that storing them in a file improves the situation. Even less clear why you believe encryption is actually beneficial at all.

Comment: Why do you need to hide and encrypt your SQL files? What is your threat model? Also, what's the deal with thread-safety? I can't understand what the problem might be.

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about the use cases for this SQL? Are they basic CRUD operations? Are they used on search pages where you have lots of different, optional criteria and JOINs on many tables?

Comment: Sounds like he's loading queries into code probably caching them in memory. Storing SQL in the DB sounds like storing code in the DB and that's a very bad idea. For your application that might be _ok_ I don't know, but in my option, everything that is required for the application to run should be in version control. Otherwise, something might break for no good reason. 

Best practices for SQL depend on the use-case. Are you a DBA? SQL files probably are ok maybe even a DB. Are these queries that are required for the user's page to load? Probably version control with the application code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice to represent SQL in program source code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177357/best-practice-to-represent-sql-in-program-source-code)

Answer (score 1):

Solution options

- Use an ORM like [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)
- Keep the queries and operations with the database as [parameterized](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types?view=netframework-4.8) stored procedures
- Use a [materialized view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view)

It will be faster (the server can compile and prepare the query ahead of time) and provide protection from SQL injection attacks. EF will also compile queries and even cache. EF also has the benefit of easier unit testing (via repository pattern and mocking).

Answer (score 0):

There should be separation of concern in your coding, sql queries should be created as stored procedures or/and scalar value functions accepting parameters if required. All you have to do in your c# code after validation if necessary,  is to call the desired stored procedure or function,passing parameters if required. This will make your codes lighter , scalable and prevent database attack  .

Answer (score 0):

I (mostly) completely agree with you. SQL in string literals is just the weirdest cultural practice, now making a comeback thanks to Dapper.

My answer to this is [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst&ssr=false#overview). Your sql lives in .sql files. You edit it in a real environment, connected to your DB with intellisense and syntax checking. Every time you save, QueryFirst generates the C# wrapper that lets you call your query. The results are returned as a list of POCOs, which are generated, so you have nothing to maintain in the C# as your query evolves. If you're worried about the security of your queries, they're copied into the generated classes and compiled, so you would need to reverse-engineer the binary to access them.

I'm not sure I understand your concern about thread safety. There are no thread safety problems of my approach that I'm aware of.

Comment: *"SQL in string literals is just the weirdest cultural practice"* - what's weird about it? All source code is string literals.

Comment: ...yes but source code in an editor can be parsed and syntax validated as you type. Text in string literals can't. 
The nearest analogy is markup. 5 minutes after the invention of HTML we had templating approaches that let you generate HTML on the fly. Templates live separately from application code. Think razor. Your editor validates your template. We could have done all that for SQL. Why on earth did it never happen?

Comment: I really don't know why language support never happened for inline SQL. I would guess it's because once upon a time it was considered too complicated to implement, and nowadays it's just considered low priority if not a downright competitor against bloated ORM frameworks.

Comment: Indeed. Well I'm happy to say I fixed that, at least for C#.